# Kompose feature similar to docker-compose links

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kompose

We are doing a POC using docker for integration tests.
We have a container with the image of an api and another container with one mongodb.

The api container must access mongodb via db-mongo-dev-company.aws.local, so I put the following entry in docker-compose:

links:
     - "mongodb: db-mongo-dev-company.aws.local"

It works perfectly with "docker-compose up".

The problem is that kompose does not have support for the feature "links", according to the following link:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/blob/master/docs/conversion.md

We can't find an alternative to make this link, do you have any idea?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be using Docker links at all at this point.  In plain Compose you can refer to other services using the name declared in the YAML file as a DNS name, and I’d expect Kompose would create a Kubernetes Service object so the same thing works.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for answer. When you say "name declared" you want to say the name in the tag "container_name" at docker-compose? If yes, i tryed, but the container_name cant have the dot character present in "db-mongo-dev-company.aws.local url", emitting the message "a DNS-1123 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and muststart and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or '123-abc', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')".

Comment: I mean the title of the block, and it won’t have any DNS domain name (just something like “db-mongo-dev-company”).  If you declare a `container_name:` that will work too, but it’s not really necessary.

Comment: Ok, given i declared the title of the block with "db-mongo-dev-company", do you know how i can set the rest of url with "aws.local"? Have an option in docker-compose to set the dns? Thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze , are you here?

Comment: I'd change your service's configuration to not use the suffix.  It'll be extra problematic running under Kubernetes, where things are generally found in a `.namespace_name.svc.cluster.local` DNS domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this situation, I simply changed the url in the properties of the api project.

Example:
I Have a file named bootstrap.yaml in src/main/resources that is looking for the spring cloud. In the DockerFile, after i pull the image of the api, i replace the file by another bootstrap.yaml file with another properties, changing the url of the mongodb.